# SuiteCRM: Module not showing in Task related to dropdown

Tags: suitecrm

I having issues with some custom modules not showing in the Task 'related to' dropdown field, therefore I cant add Tasks for these modules.

I've done the usual Repair/Rebuild, Rebuild Relationships and file checked permissions to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing these issues? I seem to vaguely remember back in the mists of SugarCRM being able to append to a variable to do a hacked fix for this.

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Its SuiteCRM version 7.9.11 btw

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding the module names into the following drop downs:

- parent_type_display
- record_type_display

Repair/Rebuild and it all worked fine. Still not sure why the modules weren't added originally.